# Getting Duplicates in Person ID and ASSIGNMENT_ID

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This is the query I'm using:

```
select  DISTINCT  "HRG_GOAL_ACCESS"."PERSON_ID" as "PERSON_ID",
     "HRG_GOAL_ACCESS"."BUSINESS_GROUP_ID" as "BUSINESS_GROUP_ID",
     "HRG_GOALS"."GOAL_ID" as "GOAL_ID",
     "HRG_GOALS"."ASSIGNMENT_ID" as "ASSIGNMENT_ID",
     "HRG_GOALS"."GOAL_NAME" as "GOAL_NAME",
     "HRG_MASS_REQ_RESULTS"."ORGANIZATION_ID" as "ORGANIZATION_ID",
     "HRG_MASS_REQ_RESULTS"."RESULT_CODE" as "RESULT_CODE",
     "HRG_GOAL_PLN_ASSIGNMENTS"."CREATED_BY" as "CREATED_BY" 
 from   "FUSION"."HRG_GOAL_PLN_ASSIGNMENTS" "HRG_GOAL_PLN_ASSIGNMENTS",
    "FUSION"."HRG_MASS_REQ_RESULTS" "HRG_MASS_REQ_RESULTS",
    "FUSION"."HRG_GOALS" "HRG_GOALS",
    "FUSION"."HRG_GOAL_ACCESS" "HRG_GOAL_ACCESS" 
 where   "HRG_GOAL_ACCESS"."PERSON_ID"="HRG_GOALS"."PERSON_ID"
 and     "HRG_MASS_REQ_RESULTS"."PERSON_ID"="HRG_GOALS"."PERSON_ID"
 and     "HRG_GOAL_PLN_ASSIGNMENTS"."PERSON_ID"="HRG_MASS_REQ_RESULTS"."PERSON_ID"
```

Output

```
PERSON_ID        BUSINESS_GROUP_ID GOAL_ID          ASSIGNMENT_ID  GOAL_NAME RESULT_CODE          CREATED_BY 
---------------- ----------------- --------------- --------------- ------------------ -------------------- -------------------
300000048030404  1                 300000137711224 300000048033078 NANO_CLASS            SUCCESS anonymous  G_1 
300000048030404  1                 300000137637946 300000048033078 INCREASE SALES BY 40% SUCCESS REDDI.SAREDDY G_1 
300000048030404  1                 300000137637946 300000048033078 INCREASE SALES BY 40% SUCCESS CURTIS.FEITTY
```

Comment: What is your expected result, and what result do you get?

Comment: I need to avoid duplicates ...? can I add any thing..

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Also you do not Need to define aliasses if the Name is equals to the table Name. Which makes it more readable

Comment: Are you having duplicated values in a query with DISTINCT? are you sure?

Comment: Please add the ddl and some sample data

Comment: You have to decide which other values to return for each distinct person id/assigbment id.

Comment: I have added DISTINCT then also getting some duplicates so please any modification is there please modify it and share me back

Comment: @Sudakar DISTINCT only removes rows where all columns are equal.

Comment: Yes Person Id & ASSIGNMENT_ID  im getting duplicates

Comment: @Sudakar Show a table with example of these duplicate, that way you have a chance to get an answer.

Comment: Output:-PERSON_ID (300000048030404)
BUSINESS_GROUP_ID (1)
GOAL_ID (300000137711224)
ASSIGNMENT_ID (300000048033078)
GOAL_NAME (NANO_CLASS)
RESULT_CODE (SUCCESS)
CREATED_BY (anonymous)
G_1
PERSON_ID (300000048030404)
BUSINESS_GROUP_ID (1)
GOAL_ID (300000137637946)
ASSIGNMENT_ID (300000048033078)
GOAL_NAME (INCREASE SALES BY 40%)
RESULT_CODE (SUCCESS)
CREATED_BY (REDDI.SAREDDY)
G_1
PERSON_ID (300000048030404)
BUSINESS_GROUP_ID (1)
GOAL_ID (300000137637946)
ASSIGNMENT_ID (300000048033078)
GOAL_NAME (INCREASE SALES BY 40%)
RESULT_CODE (SUCCESS)
CREATED_BY (CURTIS.FEITTY)

Comment: can u please check Above Output getting Person ID & A_Id duplicates

Comment: A more useful Tip Of The Day: please **edit your question** to include additional information. Comments are for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output does not contain duplicates. You have more than one row for `PERSON_ID (300000048030404)` but that's because the master table (? HRG_GOAL_ACCESS ?) has multiple rows in its child tables.

Each row has different details, so the set is valid. There are different values of  `HRG_GOALS.GOAL_ID`, `HRG_GOALS.GOAL_NAME` and `HRG_GOAL_PLN_ASSIGNMENTS.CREATED_BY`.

If this response does not make you happy you need to explain more clearly what your desire output would look like. Alternatively you need to figure out your data model and understand why your query returns the data it does. Probably you have a missing join condition; the use of `distinct` could be hindering you in finding that out.